# Is there a Linux image viewer that can browse images by a specific order?

Tags: sort, software-rec, images

I've accumulated hundreds of pictures and I'd like to sort them. For that purpose, more often than not, I check a list of them in Thunar, sorted by size, and then watch them with an image viewer.

The problem is that any image viewer I know (most notable eog and nomacs), when provide pagination of images, uses sort by name as the default order. Thus, the order seen in Thunar and the order seen in the image viewer are not the same.

Is there any image viewer that allows pagination by a specific sort? I know sorting in Thunar is unique to Thunar itself.

Comment: `gwenview` should allow sorting by a few criteria like date, size, name...

Comment: Pix offers the functionality

Comment: @rudib seems like I already tried Gwenview but missed that it had this feature. Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using [sxiv](https://github.com/muennich/sxiv):**

If your file names don’t contain newlines, it’s easy. This works because `sxiv -` accepts stdin:

```
ls -Sd -- *.png | sxiv -
```

This GNU variant uses a NUL terminated list and allows you to use the power of `find`. If you want recursion, remove `-maxdepth 1`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.png' -printf '%s\t%f\0' |
sort -znr | cut -z -f'2-' | xargs -r0 sxiv
```

**Using [feh](https://github.com/derf/feh):**

```
feh -S size --reverse ./*.png
```

feh also allows `mtime`, `format` and more. See its man page.

---

All of the above solutions open an image viewer with the largest image first. Replace `*.png` with anything you want.

Answer (score 3):

With the `zsh` shell and any image viewer that will display the images in the order they are given on the command line, you can use the `oL` glob qualifier to sort a glob expansion by size:

```
feh ./*.jpg(oL) # from smallest to largest
feh ./*.jpg(OL) # from largest to smallest
feh ./*.jpg(^oL) # from largest to smallest
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend: PLIO Image Viewer. PLIO means Pleasant Image Order.

Sorts images by width, height, size, name, namestructure, aspect ratio, modification date, brightness, color. Also allows the order of the images to be changed arbitrarily.

Also has bulk renaming, so that the new image order is reflected in the filenames and therefore being persistent afterwards.

Instead of list/treeview, each directory with images is represented as a thumbnail in a 2D array.

PLIO can be found here: https://codeberg.org/klartext/plio

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product/project?

Comment: Yes, I am. I should have mentioned it, I guess. The missing sort options in other viewers are the reason, why plio exists. As I now see, feh has also a lot of options to sort by (didn't looked it up until now). But as far as I can see, the sort can't be changed at runtime and is fixed by the command line switches. So there is a good reason to have another tool at hand.

Comment: Alright; you must disclose that affiliation in your posts on SE or you risk having posts deleted and your account suspended. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/promotion in the help center and [edit] all of your plio answers accordingly. Thank you!